# Why does QAction not have a default constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, qaction

Most classes in Qt have a default constructor. Many classes take a `QObject*` or `QWidget*` as constructor argument with default value `nullptr`. The class `QAction` also has such a constructor taking a `QObject*` as argument, but there is no default value. Therefore, `QAction` is not default constructable. Why is that? Does a `QAction` really need to have a parent? Or is there anything else different in `QAction` that explains this inconsistency?

Comment: It has a default value now in [Qt 5.7](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qaction.h?h=5.7#n93). However, it did not have a default value in [Qt 5.6](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qaction.h?h=5.6.2#n87).

Comment: @Mike Good catch. I'm working with Qt 5.5 and did not know of the change. This explains it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but there could be a reason it was done like this originally. `QWidget::addAction(QAction*)` does not take ownership of the `QAction` object, so maybe this was a way to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess here but I would say there is no reason behind it.

In Qt 4.8 the signature is (as you mentioned) without default value for parent.

```
QAction(QObject * parent)
```

see http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html

This changes in Qt 5.7 though

```
QAction(QObject *parent = nullptr)
```

see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html

So I assume it was an accidental inconsistency which finally got fixed with Qt 5.7.